# How to remove Cesium map bottom real time meter

Tags: openlayers, cesiumjs

I want to remove Cesium map bottom real time meter entities but i am not able to remove this.

Please see image what i want to remove in this map.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dial in the lower-left is called the `animation` widget, and the bar across the bottom is the `timeline` widget.  You can turn them off when the Cesium viewer is first constructed, like this:

```js
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
  animation: false,
  timeline: false
});
```